# Make number of columns equal to number of column headers

Tags: php, mysqli, dynamic, html-table

I'm trying to get a table created in PHP where I will have a bunch of column headers set by a form, and then the table will show those columns only.

So the table could have 4 columns or 6 depending on the date range put in.

What would be the best way going about this, as I have tried a few things, but nothing gets near what I want.

Here is some code:

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Last Name</td>';
echo '<th>First Name</td>';
if($column_date1 != '') { echo '<th>' . $column_date1 . '</td>'; }
if($column_date2 != '') { echo '<th>' . $column_date2 . '</td>'; }
if($column_date3 != '') { echo '<th>' . $column_date3 . '</td>'; }
if($column_date4 != '') { echo '<th>' . $column_date4 . '</td>'; }
if($column_date5 != '') { echo '<th>' . $column_date5 . '</td>'; }
echo '</tr>';

// I will have a loop in here that searches records in a database.
$mysqliFunctionResult = $mysqliFunction->query($mysqliFunctionQuery);
while($line = $mysqliFunctionResult->fetch_assoc()) {
?><tr>
    <td><?php echo $line['tabledata1']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $line['tabledata2']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $line['tabledata3']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $line['tabledata4']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $line['tabledata5']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: This will probably work much better if you do it client side with javascript or jquery nonetheless, writing an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I may be miss understanding your answer but. here's my go at it.

```
/******************************
 * get the $database with same
 * names as the $_POST 
 *****************************/

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <?php // make the headers 
    foreach ($_POST as $column => $inside) {
        if (!empty($column)) {
            echo "<th>" . $column . "<th>";
        }
     }   
    ?>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
foreach($database, $row) {
    foreach ($_POST as $column) {
        if (!empty($column)) {
            $row[$column];
        }
     }   
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I just threw this together, I doubt it's anywhere near perfect but maybe give you an idea of one way to do it perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Do a foreach($key => $value) on the $_post data. Then use $key to access the data you pulled. For each key, echo the corresponding data you want to show.

Comment: Sorry I dont have code example, sent from phone. If it is not clear i will edit

Answer (score 0):

Easier if you can save the postdata like an array:

```
foreach($_POST['column_date'] as $column_date)
    if("" != $column_date)
        echo '<th>' . $column_date . '</td>';
```

...you'd have to name the input-fields column_date[1] etc.